# Which math modules to specialize in as a mathematics undergraduate if I want to study theoretical physics at masters?

Tags: education

I am currently studying Mathematics as third year student, which is the last year in our french based system in Algeria. But I would like to pursue a masters degree in theoretical physics. The main courses I have completed so far are linear algebra, measure theory, introduction to topology, real analysis and complex analysis(introduction), geometry, prob and stats, optimization without constrains and equations used in mathematical physics.

As part of the last semester my university allows us to chose specialities (I think it's not a good idea to chose them early enough) which are divided into four with the respective modules taught in brackets; Abstract algebra (Field theory and Group theory), Analysis ( Introduction to the theory of linear operators and Partial differential equations), Probability and Stats ( Inferential statistics and Introduction to random processes) and finally Operational research (Optimization with constrains and linear programming).

I think the choice of specializing remains on Analysis and Abstract algebra which are more used in theoretical physics other than the rest, but between the two I do not know which one will give me a better advantage.

Comment: I once had a senior who had done something similar situation to you (who I admire much). IIRC he had studied the math from books written by physicists on it. For example, he referred to MTW for learning tensors instead of some rigorous book. And btw, the word you want to look up is "mathematical physics"

Comment: I am aware of mathematical physics and unfortunately in my country there is no university offering masters in mathematical physics, the choices are radiation physics, medical physics, theoretical physics, nuclear security, materials physics and fluid dynamics and energetics

Comment: I would think your biggest issue facing into a physics-centered masters is that actual of physics.  I'd want to see some proof of interest and knowledge in physics to allow you into a course at that level (or you will at best be required to do a lot of catch-up courses in physics).  You'd likely be competing with physics BScs for the places.

Comment: Oh :( I think you may get  more responses if you post this on the academia stackexchange becoz it's mostly about education and university stuff

Comment: @StephenG, I regularly read physics text books though I have been more concentration on quantum mechanics and special relativity aided through some MIT opencoursewave lectures

Comment: While you may have some knowledge of physics I would be prepared to be told by interviewers that they have reservations about your practical knowledge of physics and to be told (at best) that you have to do mandatory physics courses to get up to speed to be accepted into an masters course.  Theoretical physics is going to be in heavy demand by the best physics grads.  I'd strongly suggest contacting the appropriate people in the masters programs that interest you and discussing this with them to get a feel for what awaits.